# How could i store my Value from my NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray` from API, it has many objects and every object has 8 key/value pairs.

I want to use one value to store 8 key/value pair in another array of my  objects.

[image: Tree]

I have tried `containsObject` & `indexOfObject`
for `IndexOfObject`

I got `NSNotFound` for `containsObject` and **it crashed**!

How do i do this?

Comment: which one you want to catch?

Comment: i want to catch the index of value i got it , for example if i get a name , i want to know the name was which index , and the index's all value.

Comment: that what i am asking any particular value you want to catch or whole 8 key/Values ?

Comment: @PiyushPatel i want use one value , to catch all value from same Index.

Comment: you mean to say you want to store 8 key/value pair in another array of your 46 objects right ?

Comment: I think OP wants to retrieve the index where some key is equal to some specific value.

Comment: @PiyushPatel yes! you got it! i want this

Comment: need to update the question and specify your requirement clearly.

Comment: @luk2302 yes, my question is it , i want to get another 7 pair value ,from my one value ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`.

```
foundArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", name]];
foundDictionary = foundArray.firstObject;
```

Or you can do this with `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` or another `index…PassingTest:` method.

```
index = [array indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    return [[obj objectForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:name];
}];
if (index != NSNotFound)
    foundDictionary = [foundArray objectAtIndex:index];
```